# How to "turn off" scientific notation in read.csv (or other read functions) in R?

Tags: r, csv, scientific-notation, read.csv

I have a ".csv" data file that I want to read into R and convert into a data frame. One of the columns of the data file contains 9-digit product codes, which is either a mix of numbers and characters, or just numbers. For example:

```
214E1100
213E1200
3151E100
293JS941
29EKS0941
80129849
29012841
29310941
```

I've been using `read.csv` to read in this data file. 
The problem arises for values where there's an "E" character sandwiched by numbers. i.e.

```
213E1200
3151E100
```

R is reading this as numbers and converts it into the exponential form `213E+1200` or `3.151E+103` once the data is read in. I've tried setting the `colClasses` to `"character"` so it reads in everything as characters 
i.e. using `read.csv("DATA.csv", colClasses = "character")`
but the problem still persists.

Is there any way to turn off the scientific notation, so R simply reads in the whole data set (or simply this column) as characters/strings and doesn't convert it to numerics? I know there's a way to do this for `write.csv`, but I couldn't find any solutions for `read.csv`.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this!

Answer (score 2):

If you type in `?read.csv`, the documentation says on `colClasses`: "A **vector** of classes to be assumed for the columns. Recycled as necessary." Thus, if you want to read in all columns as characters you should specify `colClasses` as follows:

```
colClasses=c(rep("character",5)) # 5 here being the number of columns of your data
```